# Profile Image cuts off in the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a simple custom UITableViewCell which has profile image on the left, title and detailsLabel on the right. I have used Auto Layout constraints to set all the views on the screen. But the detailsLable text is short and profile image cuts off.

Let me know how to fix it. I could make the image small which is shorter than the height of title and label combined, but I want the big image.

[image]

```
// adding subviews
contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
contentView.addSubview(jobTitleDetailedLabel)

// constraint for the views  

    profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.topAnchor,     constant:10).isActive = true
    profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.leadin    gAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50).isActive = true
profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:50).isActive = true

    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.topAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.profileImageView.trailingAnchor,  constant:10).isActive = true
nameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

jobTitleDetailedLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.nameLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
jobTitleDetailedLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.profileImageView.trailingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
jobTitleDetailedLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
jobTitleDetailedLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
```

Comment: This is issue of your cell height. What you are returning in height  in tableview delegate ?

Comment: OR just add yourtableview.rowHeight = UITableviewAutomaticDimention and estimateRowHeight = 60

Comment: I did not have any delegate methods.

Comment: Then add that. or try my second comment it will resize your cell according to you content but for that you need to give proper constraints

Comment: I tried both of the code already and it did not do any adjustment on the height whatsoever. :(

Answer (score 1):

Just add   jobTitleDetailedLabel  height constrain to be `greaterThanOrEqualToConstant` profileImageView height  + 10  for Margin

because if `jobTitleDetailedLabel` hight is less than `Image hight` it will make it small cell row

```
self.jobTitleDetailedLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

Comment: If the answer solved your issue, you should mark it as an answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to constrain the cell's contentView's bottom anchor to be greaterThanOrEqualTo both the profileImageView's bottom anchor and the jobTitleDetailedLabel's bottom anchor. The cell will expand according to whichever is larger.

So you need to remove the jobTitleDetailedLabel's bottom anchor constraint and add:

```
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: jobTitleDetailedLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
```

Also set the contentHuggingPriority of the nameLabel to high in order to ensure that the nameLabel keeps its intrinsic height (the height the text takes up).

```
nameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
```

Finally set the cell's row height to UITableviewAutomaticDimension  in the storyboard or through code -  `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: what if jobTitleDetailedLabel  text is bigger than Image Hight

Comment: Then set the contentView's bottom anchor to be greater than or equal to the bottom anchor of the jobTitleDetailedLabel

Comment: still cell automation hight will make small according to text

Comment: I don't think so because the contentView's bottom will be constrained to the bottom of the textLabel if it is lower than the imageView

Comment: Then set the contentView's bottom anchor to be greater than or equal to the bottom anchor  of jobTitleDetailedLabel , what  if jobTitleDetailedLabel  have one word then content view will equal to it that may be less image height

Comment: There will be 2 constraints on the contentView's bottom anchor.  One to be equal to the bottom of the imageView. Another greater than or equal to the bottom of the label. The one to the image view should have a lower priority. So the bottom of the content view is always equal to or greater than the bottom of the image view but will expand if the text label's bottom anchor is lower than the imageView's

Comment: Thanks I will, this is a better solution.

Comment: There is much than answer just edit yours to remove downvote

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish while your solution does work to fix the cell's size it seems a bit wasteful to have the label take up more space than it needs. It's best to keep labels at their Intrinsic Content Size. Also an unintended consequence of setting the height to a fixed minimum constant would be that the text of the label gets vertically centered within the label if it were only a few words, it wouldn't align to the top.

Comment: As i told you before you can do it more accurate that i set solution according to his solution